# Dynamics AX Option in Visual Studio for Creating AX SSRS Report?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

We have to create ssrs reports for Dynamics AX. When my friend tried to follow tutorials which says Got to Visual Studio- File -Dynamics AX- Dynamics AX Reporting Project. This is the path to follow. But when i click on File , I dont see Dynamics AX Option available. COuld you please let me know how can i get that option? What needs to be done/installed to get that option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the Visual Studio Tools pieces from the AX 2012 install ISO.

See here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd309576.aspx

> Visual Studio Tools integrate the development of Microsoft Dynamics AX
>   with Microsoft Visual Studio. Developers can use these tools to create
>   managed code that accesses X++ objects. Developers can also use the
>   tools to create or modify controls for Enterprise Portal for Microsoft
>   Dynamics AX and reports for Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services.
>   For more information about Visual Studio Tools, see Visual Studio
>   Development for Microsoft Dynamics AX.

Answer (score 0):

Install Visual Studio Tools

Use this procedure to install Visual Studio Tools. If you install other Microsoft Dynamics AX components at the same time, the installation pages vary, depending on the components that you are installing.

Start Microsoft Dynamics AX Setup. Under Install, select Microsoft Dynamics AX components.

You can use this link : 
[Install visual studio component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/appuser-itpro/install-visual-studio-tools)

Answer (score 0):

first you need to install compatible visual studio,
for example ax 2012 rtm, ax 2012, and ax 2012 fpp: compatible to visual studio 2010, 2013 at least professional edition (I recommended using visual studio 2010 ultimate)

for ax 2012 r2, r3, compatible using visual studio 2013 etc

then install that tools on developer server, and install the visual studio tools that comes in ax 2012 installation cd/dvd/iso's